# Evaluating predicted probabilities with histogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a dataframe containing european football matches, their full time result and implied probability for home win result (using bookies odds).
looks as follow:

```
Div     Date HomeTeam       AwayTeam FTR  PSH  PSD  PSA PSCH PSCD PSCA homeprob
F2 28/07/17    Brest    Chateauroux   A 2.01 3.07 4.92 1.91 3.27 5.13     0.50
F2 28/07/17    Nimes          Reims   A 2.33 3.05 3.73 2.34 3.12 3.62     0.43
...
```

So I created a histogram with the implied probability on the x axis and frequency on the y axis. And now I want to plot on the same graph the number of actual wins for each homeprob value (so I can compare observed vs expected)
this is the graph I have so far

[image]

I'm just not sure how to. Was thinking of running a loop through every possible value of `homeprob` and to add count if `FTR == "H"` ?

btw - please let me know if you think there is better way to compare observed and expected.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using `cut` to bin the `homeprob` variable into discrete intervals?  You could then use dplyr commands to group by and count home wins, and a third encoding such as color for the actual wins (although it would then have to be a bar chart).

Comment: thanks for your comment! I used cut and now I have 20 groups. Also added a column to the dataframe with group value (for example (0.414 - 0.449] ) but I'm not sure how do I build the loop to count the number of homewins for each group. Tried using a for loop but no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a few different options for how to compare home win probability and "H" (which I'm guessing is actual or predicted win).  As suggested in the comment, you could cut `homeprob` into buckets and use `dplyr` for aggregate statistics.  Then use color for wins or simply plot `homeprob` vs wins.

Since there are a few ways to do it, I'll give some options and a reproducible example.

Here is some made up data that is similar to yours:

```
# random normal data
randn_data <- rnorm(15000, 0.5, .05)
df <- data.frame(homeprob = randn_data)
# random uniform from 0 to 1
df$randunif <- runif(nrow(df))
# new feature is "H" if random uniform is less than homeprob
df$ftr <- ifelse(df$randunif < df$homeprob, "H", "A")
df$probcut <- cut(df$homeprob, seq(0.2, 0.8, 0.05))
```

Now you could use color for total wins, although I don't think that would be the best option because your data is normal and the frequency will be higher towards the mean:

```
library(dplyr)
df_plot1 <- df %>%
  group_by(probcut) %>%
  summarise(hprob_counts = n(), wins = sum(ftr == "H"))
# wins as color
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_plot1, aes(x = probcut, y = hprob_counts, fill = wins)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_sqrt()
```

[image]

I think it would be better to use win rate to compare the expected and observed:

```
df_plot2 <- df %>%
  group_by(probcut) %>%
  summarise(hprob_counts = n(), wins = sum(ftr == "H")) %>%
  mutate(win_rate = wins / hprob_counts)

ggplot(df_plot2, aes(x = probcut, y = hprob_counts, fill = win_rate)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_sqrt()
```

[image]

You could also just plot `homeprob` and `win_rate` without the distribution:

```
ggplot(df_plot2, aes(x = probcut, y = win_rate)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Hopefully this is more or less what you were looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help!